# Validate Digital Signature using Signature Timestamp

Tags: .net, validation, certificate, timestamping

The `X509Certificate2Collection.Import` method allows to retrieve all certificates from an executable file or from an MSI package. That's fine.

Now I want to validate the certificates. The `X509Certificate.Verify` method validates a certificate against the **current time** (the Reflector confirms: it uses `DateTime.Now`).

So my first question is how to validate the certificates against the *signed time*? An option would be to retrieve an Authenticode data, but there are no built-in support in .NET.

The second question is how to validate the signatures?